Debezium source kafka connector fails to process after db connection is lost
I'm using MySQL debezium CDC connector. The problem I have is that at some case debezium is not processing data due to lost connection to database. The only log I get is info log that debezium is trying to restore lost connection to rds, but it is not being restored.
Trying to restore lost connection to {rds-endpoint}:3306

After the restore connection log appears, message is not produced to kafka anymore and debezium_metrics_Connected metric drops to 0 (1 means it is connected). However, when I see kafka connector status it stays as Running.
debezium_metrics_Connected{context="streaming",plugin="mysql",namespace="$namespace"}   

I monitored rds metrics but cpu utilization, iops, freeable memory, connection count did not seem to be a problem. Also, cpu and memory of debezium pods did not seem to reach the limit.
Does anyone know how to deal with this issue? I want either connection to restore automatically after several tries or make connection lost not happen.
I have tried restarting the connector but it did not work. The only way to solve it was to delete a connector and redeploy it.
My environment is as follows:

confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.1.0 with https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql connectors and using Debezium 2.6.1
MySQL 8.xx
deployed debezium on kubernetes AWS EKS.
heapOptions: "-Xms1G -Xmx1G"
resource: CPU 2 / Memory 2Gi for request and limit

